# Appengine converting unicode char to blank char in urllib.unquote

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am sending encoded post data to appengine project.But appengine shows blank char in response.

I am sending this form data : 
`mdata=I%FD%FD%FE%DE%DE%E7%E7%C7%D6%F6%F6%D6%D6%0A%0A`

and my appengine response code is :

```
request_data = self.request.get('mdata')
mailhtmldata = urllib.unquote_plus(request_data)
```

And repr(request_data) and repr(mailhtmldata) is `u'I\n\n'` .Still unicode chars like "İşÇöÖü" are blank.I am sure about my sender is sending `mdata=I%FD%FD%FE%DE%DE%E7%E7%C7%D6%F6%F6%D6%D6%0A%0A`.i tested.Where is other chars in appengine ?

Thanks for all help.

Sorry for my bad english

**Update :**

This is my sender function

```
def mailSend():
    values = urllib.urlencode({'mailam' : 'deneme@hotmail.com', 'mfromname' :'Deneme Kisisi', 'mkonu' : 'This is Subject', 'mdata' : 'IıışŞşÖÖççç'})
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("xxxxxx.appspot.com")
    conn.request("POST", "/gondergitsin", values, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print data
    conn.close()
```

And this is the appengine code:

```
class mTransfer(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        mailhtmldata = urllib.unquote_plus(self.request.get('mdata'))
        x2adresx = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('mailam'))
        x2gonderenx = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('mfromname'))
        x2gondid = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(12))
        anagonderen = "Deneme <info@koorsender.appspotmail.com>"
        mailsubjdata = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('mkonu'))
        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=anagonderen, subject=mailsubjdata)
        message.to = x2adresx
        message.body = mailhtmldata
        message.html = mailhtmldata
        message.send()
        self.response.out.write("OK")
```

I tried but still i can't found a solution

**Update 2:** If you are using unicode charsets you decode it to your charset and after that you can encode it to utf-8.

Comment: What do you see in `self.request.body`? The code and your urlencoded string do not match. Start with a single letter `u'\u015e'.encode("utf-8")`. What do you get for a long pure ascii `mdata`? Where is `'\n\n'` coming from? What do you get: `curl -d mdata=I%C4%B1%C4%B1%C5%9F%C5%9E%C5%9E%C3%A7%C3%A7%C3%87%C3%96%C3%B6%C3%B6%C3%96%C3%96 http://xxxxxx.appspot.com/gondergitsin`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : curl response : u'I\u0131\u0131\u015f\u015e\u015e\xe7\xe7\xc7\xd6\xf6\xf6\xd6\xd6'

and i am trying to send mailhtml. mdata is mail html.i am sending with post method. 
thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are sending appears to be the result of url-encoding some characters expressed in `cp1254` (Windows Turkish) encoding (or the very similar `ISO-8859-9` encoding). Have you told "appengine" what encoding you are using?

We need a bit more information about "Still unicode chars like "İşÇöÖü" are blank". Blank when you look at them how? Instead of

`htmldata = urllib.unquote_plus(self.request.get('mdata'))`

do this:

```
request_data = self.request.get('mdata')
htmldata = urllib.unquote_plus(request_data)
```

and edit your question to show the results of `repr(request_data)` and `repr(htmldata)`

**Update** You say that `self.request.get('mdata')` is returning `u'I\n\n'` ... the non-ASCII characters in your data are not coming back as blank; they are being *removed*.

Somebody's code is stripping out non-ASCII characters. Something like `your_input.decode(some_encoding, 'ignore')` with `some_encoding` set to `ascii` or `UTF-8`.

Show us the code where you "told to appengine what encoding i am using(iso-8859-9)".

**Update 2** in response to posting of sending code and this comment "I am adding `# -*- coding: iso-8859-9 -*-` to top".

Putting the "coding" thing at the top of your source file is telling the Python compiler the encoding of the remainder of your **source file**. It has nothing to do with the encoding of your **data**. You could remove the # coding thing and instead of writing `'mdata' : 'IıışŞşÖÖççç'` you could write `'mdata' : 'I\xFD\xFD etc etc'` and get the same string of bytes sent to the server with the same effect. You have **NOT** told appengine what encoding you are using.

Instead of

`"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`,

I suggest that you try this:

`"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:ISO-8859-9;"`

Comment: Yes i told to appengine what encoding i am using(iso-8859-9). i edited my question . thanks

Comment: Hi,I am adding # -*- coding: iso-8859-9 -*- to top. I updated my question added all code.Thanks again

Comment: is this problem source can be mdata = part.get_payload(None,True)   ? because i am parsing an email file first.And if i can't use urlencode function and sending raw data like mdata=I%C4%B1%C4%B1%C5%9F%C5%9E%C5%9E%C3%A7%C3%A7%C3%87%C3%96%C3%B6%C3%B6%C3%96%‌​C3%96 everything OK in app engine.

thanks .

Comment: Well of course (1) it helps if you know what your input encoding is (2) if you don't tell the receiver of your output what encoding you are using, `UTF-8` has a much better chance of being the default and is much more easily detectable than `ISO-8859-9`. There is still no explanation for non-ASCII characters being stripped out.

Comment: i found problem. quopri.decodestring(mdata) is problem.when i try to change encoding to utf-8 "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 21". and i didn't found a true solution for this. how can i fix this ?

Comment: This appears to be a new problem. quopri has not been mentioned before. In any case that 0xfd should be instantly recognisable to you as the "small dotless i" encoded in ISO-8859-9. To change encoding from that to utf-8, you need to do `that.decode('ISO-8859-9').encode('UTF-8')` instead of whatever you are doing. Consider starting a new question and tell the WHOLE story at once, with all relevant code, results of `print repr(relevant_data)`, and tell us what version of what OS and what version of python you are using.

Comment: @KorcanErgün Adding the coding header only affects the encoding of the source code file, not of data it deals with. John - there's no need to re-encode the string as UTF-8 - far better to leave it as a unicode string.

Comment: @NickJohnson: about your 2 points (1) he's been told that already (2) If you know what his code is doing at any given time e.g. after "I try to change ...", that's fantastic, good luck with helping him further.

Comment: @JohnMachin In response to 2, I'm just pointing out that you should deal with unicode strings internally in code, not byte strings.

Comment: @NickJohnson: This is true; however the OP is working right on the boundary between "internal" and "external"; in particular, `urllib.urlencode` chokes on Unicode, it must be fed `str` objects. He needs specific advice, not truisms. Now he is mentioning `quopri`, and we can't give him any sensible advice until he publishes code, traceback, error message, debug output, etc.

Comment: @JohnMachin I think you're missing my point. Anything of the form `foo.decode(...).encode(...)` immediately sets off alarm bells, and unless you're really just writing something to translate between encodings, it's probably the wrong thing to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to `"utf-8"` before urlencoding:

```
mdata_ue = "I%FD%FD%FE%DE%DE%E7%E7%C7%D6%F6%F6%D6%D6%0A%0A"
mdata = urllib.unquote_plus(mdata_ue).decode('iso-8859-9')
print urllib.quote_plus(mdata.encode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
I%C4%B1%C4%B1%C5%9F%C5%9E%C5%9E%C3%A7%C3%A7%C3%87%C3%96%C3%B6%C3%B6%C3%96%C3%96\
%0A%0A
```